# while upgrading target sdk to 29 am getting crash in Android10 only

Tags: android, android-layout, android-10.0

When I am trying to upgrade the target SDK to 29 getting the below Crash

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in package:layout/abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode: Binary XML file line #23 in cpackage:layout/abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsFrameLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in com.primedia.apartmentguide.debug:layout/abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsFrameLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Field.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

I have upgraded all the dependencies in the projects but no use, When I search for a solution people are saying I need to upgrade the Calligraphy3, but I don't use this library in my project at all.

This only occurs in Android 10 it works well in other versions of android.

Comment: please share ```abc_screen_simple_overlay_action_mode```

Comment: I don't have any file with that name in my project.

Comment: This file is probably in one of the libraries added to the project. can you share file Gradle??

Comment: Do you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered a similar error. I found the answer [here](https://blog.csdn.net/bigsmart12/article/details/103291014). Not sure exactly what the problem was, but I guess it was due to the fonts. I did the following :

1. Add new dependencies

```
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'
```

2. Added font files and part of the code that will replace with the default style in case of problems

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        LayoutInflaterCompat.setFactory2(getLayoutInflater(), new IconicsLayoutInflater2(getDelegate()));
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ViewPump.init(ViewPump.builder()
                .addInterceptor(new CalligraphyInterceptor(
                        new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                                .setDefaultFontPath("font/TimesNewRoman.ttf")
                                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                                .build()))
                .build());
    }
```

3. Replaced classes that returned context

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(IconicsContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
```

to

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(ViewPumpContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
```